# python and networkx: how to change the color of nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm using python and "networkx" to randomly assign edges to nods. the nods are in 2 categories  and each category has the same number of nodes. the code is working but I have one questions: how can I change the color of nodes? now, nodes from both categories have the sam color.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = int(raw_input("Enter the number of each race to be used: "))

gamma = float(raw_input("Enter the probability of same-race ties: "))

delta = float(raw_input("Enter the probability of cross-race ties: "))
connectr11 = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=np.int32)

for i in range(0,N):
        dval = np.diag((np.random.random_sample(size=(N-i))<gamma).astype(np.int32),i)
        connectr11 += dval
        if (i>0):
                connectr11 += dval.T
##print connectr11

connectr22 = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=np.int32)

for i in range(0,N):
        dval = np.diag((np.random.random_sample(size=(N-i))<gamma).astype(np.int32),i)
        connectr22 += dval
        if (i>0):
                connectr22 += dval.T

##print connectr22

connectr12 = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=np.int32)

for i in range(0,N):
        dval = np.diag((np.random.random_sample(size=(N-i))<delta).astype(np.int32),i)
        connectr12 += dval
        if (i>0):
                connectr12 += dval.T

##print connectr12


connectr21 = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=np.int32)

for i in range(0,N):
        dval = np.diag((np.random.random_sample(size=(N-i))<delta).astype(np.int32),i)
        connectr12 += dval
        if (i>0):
                connectr12 += dval.T
##print connectr21

concr1x=np.concatenate((connectr11, connectr12), axis=0)
concrx2=np.concatenate((connectr21, connectr22), axis=0)
concr12=np.concatenate((concr1x, concrx2), axis=1)
##print concr12


print concr12


A=np.matrix(concr12)
G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)


for i in range(0,N):
    if i < N: 
        G.node[i] = 1
        node_color='b'
    else:
        G.node[i] = 0
        node_color='r'



nx.draw_circular(G, node_color=node_color)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Lots of examples of drawings with code here: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/gallery.html

Answer (score 3):

You want your node_color to be a list. In your 2nd to last line, assigning node_color = node_color makes ALL of the nodes whatever the last value assigned to node_color is. What you want is a list of equal length to the number of nodes you have.

```
    node_colors =[]
    node_colors.append('r')
```

try:

```
    for i in range(0,N):
        if i < N:
           node_colors.append('b')
        else: 
           node_colors.append('r')
    nx.draw_circular(G, node_color = node_colors)
    plt.show()
```